# Is it possible to create rel="noindex, nofollow" for a single post if contain bad keywords?

Tags: single

I run a project using "Auto Generated Content" plugin, so my site will have tons of content instantly. Some post will contain unwanted and bad keywords, so it will need to be excluded from search engine. But I don't know how to do this.

Is it possible to create `rel="noindex, nofollow"` for a single post if contain some specific bad keywords?

I tried this little plugin, but still not works.

```
function noindex_bad_words() {
      if (is_single()){
       //add more keywords in regex code
       $block_bad_words="/\b(badwords|badkeyword)\b/";
        if (preg_match($block_bad_words,strtolower(get_search_query()))) {
          echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />';
          }
          else
          {
          echo '<meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />';
          }
       }
    }
add_action('wp_head', 'noindex_bad_words');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <?php 

        if (is_single()){
            //add more keywords in regex code
            $badWords = array("badwords","badkeyword");
            $string = get_the_content();
            $matches = array();
            $matchFound = '';
            $matchFound = preg_match_all("/\b(" . implode($badWords,"|") . ")\b/i",$string,$matches);
        }

    ?>
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow <?php echo $matchFound ?>" />
    <?php wp_head() ?>
    </head>
```

Comment: Any detail instruction how to implement those code in header.php? I tried it but shown error in the homepage. :(

Comment: Please check the above updated code. Hope it helps :)

Comment: I've added the code. I've replaced the "badwords" with specific word as I need, and then check the page source for a single page which contain the keyword. Unfortunately, it's looks not works.

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Comment: See on this: http://prntscr.com/g8avov

Comment: if those bad-words contain by the post content then the above code will work.

Comment: @user3888958 is there another location (or another type of content) you want to check for bad words?

Comment: yes,  you can get the content which is based on post_id.